# PMF table probabilities

Tags: probability

Given that U and V are independent and identically distributed Ber(p) random
variables and then defining X = 2|U − V|− 1 and Y = U + V − 1. How would I find the joint pmf of X and Y (as a table). I started this question by first making another table for U, V, X, Y using the equations given:

```
U  V  X   Y
0  0  -1  -1
0  1  1   0
1  0  1   0
1  1  -1  1
```

So for the pmf table,

```
             Y

      X     -1        0        1

     -1     (1-p)^2   0        p^2
      1      0        2p(1-p)  0
```

How do I figure out the probabilities in terms of p ? Could anyone please help with this?

Comment: Take one case as example. $P(U = 1, V = 1) = P(U = 1) . P(V = 1) = p^2$

Comment: Yes, I understand the ones with 0 and 1 but what about the ones with -1? So lets say P(U=-1,V=-1), how would I do that

Comment: U and V don't take value $-1$, it's X and Y.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I meant X and Y

Comment: Read my first comment again. Where will you write that probability $p^2$  in the joint distribution table? What happens with X and Y when both U and V take value $1$? Refer to your first table which is correct btw.

Comment: Hey @math_noob, can you check to see the answer I edited in my question?

Comment: The question is highly confusing in its present form -- one has to read the comments in order to understand that you answered your own question. Please mark this clearly so that the question makes sense by itself.